# Will Appstore accept this kind of application?

Tags: iphone, app-store

So I already have 2 versions out on appstore..

One app is a free but limited version.

The other is a paid unlimited. The basic layout..

I have had questions from companies wanting to buy the app and give to their employees. So they don't have to buy the app with their personal accounts..

So I was thinking of releasing a 3rd version that prompts the user for a license key on first start, if the key is valid the app starts and works until reinstalled or w/e. If the key is invalid the app just keeps prompting for a valid license.

Now I remembered reading somewhere that apple wouldn't allow apps that had no public function or something like that. Which this app wont have unless u have a valid license.. 
But since I do also provide a valid public version of the app, will this one get accepted? Or have they removed theese rules?

Any insight in the matter would be helpful!

Edit:

Forgot to mention that the reason im looking to use the license is because i have the same app for android and want the companies to be able to buy for both device types, not just apple devices.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something very similar to this some time ago, they seemed ok with it (then at least), they just asked for a license key in the complementary info (during the app submission) to go through all their usual validation tests.

Comment: @Anders, most of the apps on the app store have no public function :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should use the B2B functionality in ITunes Connect: http://developer.apple.com/support/ios/volume-purchase-program.html

Also check: https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/volume/

Comment: I forgot to add that I want the license to work on all devices so this wont help me if the company has android devices they want to buy to aswell. But thanks for the info

Answer (score 1):

[Klassmating](https://klassmating.com/) has an app in the app store that has no public functionality unless you are a student at a specific university. So it seems like you can have apps like that.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing exactly, I would assume Apple would reject such an app from the store (mainly because it would allow you to sell applications "behind their back" - i.e. sell licence keys and not using in-app purchase) :-)

However, there are two possible solutions to your problem that come to my mind:

1. Create and distribute gift codes (would be a problem if you had to give out too many of them).
2. Do an ad-hoc distribution of your app to the companies. Basically they would need your application bundle and an ad-hoc mobile provision file. Then they can simply install your application by dragging it to iTunes.

Comment: Apple does state tha "They are for non-commercial use and will expire four weeks after they are requested." and im not really looking to do the ad-hoc deal since i want to do a simular app to android and have the license work for any kind of device.

Comment: Could you provide a reference to where they state this? The ad-hoc provisioning profiles I created have an expiry time of a year - well enough to provide an update in between.

Comment: Was as a reply to 1. On the request promo codes section of a paid app.

Comment: Ah ok I understand, but they mean the promo codes expire after four weeks when unused. Once the code is used and the app is installed you'd be good to go - however, after reading the other answers I'd also suggest to go with the B2B programme.

Answer (score 1):

There are different official iPhone  [application distribution methods.](http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/distribute.html)

In which for your current requirement,I suppose you can use the Custom B2B Apps,where you can deliver apps directly to your business customers who have a Volume Purchase Program account.You can get more information from the link provided above.

cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I too have had an app in the app store which works like this. You have to provide them with a key/licence to access the app functionality so they can test it fully.

Answer (score 0):

I've had an app rejected for this very reason - required a username and password, not a licence key, but was free.  They said in contravened the licence terms regarding in app purchases.
Mine allowed time limited free trials from within the app, but full functionality was restricted to purchases outside the app.  Apple wanted their 30% cut of the subscription cost so it was no dice for us.

On the other hand, the app store review process is seemingly entirely random, so who knows.

Comment: Ok, think I will try it out and see where it goes from there.. Thanks