# avoiding app store subscription (and implementing your own)

Tags: app-store

We're building a cloud service that will enable users using misc mobile devices (iPhones, Androids, new Nokias...) to sync their data to the cloud. We plan to charge for the device cloud sync capability through a monthly subscription on our website. Our users will pay a single monthly subscription and then use the service across all their devices, regardless of the platform. Users without subscription will be able to use parts of the app without the cloud sync.

Will the kind folks at the AppStore accept this kind of behavior since we're in a way avoiding the in app purchases - the app will be free, and the user will be paying for the service on our website.

I am aware that the Kindle app for iOS uses the same behavior, so I am guessing this should be possible. From what I saw here:
  [Will Appstore accept this kind of application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768417/will-appstore-accept-this-kind-of-application)
it should be applicable in my case. Does anyone else have any additional info regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know yes as spotify, mog and other music streaming services all behave this way